# MimeMessage cannot read the attachment correctly in C#

Tags: c#, gmail, imap, email-attachments, mime-message

Sorry if the question is similar to others already asked but I can't solve it in anyway with the code I found here and on GitHub.

I have to develop a job that runs every day and downloads the attachment of a specific email.
The problem is that the program behaves as if the attachment is empty, although it is not.

Below is the code I am using:

PS: I specify that I am a junior developer, surely my code is not the best :)

```
                client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 993);
                client.Authenticate(USERID, PASSWORD); 

                var inbox = client.Inbox;
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                {
                    var message = inbox.GetMessage(i); 


                    var today = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                    var tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);

                    var address = InternetAddress.Parse("String who contains the email address");

                    if (message.Date > today && message.Date < tomorrow && message.From.Contains(address))
                    {
                        var attachments = message.Attachments; 

                        foreach(var attachment in attachments)
                        {
                            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                            {

                                UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
                                attachment.ContentType.CharsetEncoding = utf8;
                                attachment.WriteTo(ms);

                            }
                        }


                    }
                    break;
                }
```

EDIT:

I was able to solve the problem. The MimeEntity object was not the final object I had to load, it needed a Parse() in MessagePart to take only the body of the text, in doing so I was able to use the method that the guy advised me in the comments.
I fixed the loops by filtering before the for to save time.

```
      var client = new ImapClient();
        client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 993);
        client.Authenticate(USERID, PASSWORD);

        var inbox = client.Inbox;
        inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

        var today = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        var query = SearchQuery.SentOn(today).And (SearchQuery.FromContains(USERID_OF_SENDER)); 
        var messageUid = inbox.Search(query);


        foreach(UniqueId uid in messageUid)
        {
     
                var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);         
                var attachments = message.Attachments;

                foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments)
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        if (attachment is MessagePart)
                        {
                            var part = (MessagePart)attachment; 
                            part.Message.WriteTo(ms);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var part = (MimePart)attachment;
                            part.Content.DecodeTo(ms);
                        }
                        //method for upload the file
                    }
                }                   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are intending to do, but the following 2 lines are guaranteed to be wrong:

```
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
attachment.ContentType.CharsetEncoding = utf8;
```

The following line writes the MIME entity which is probably not what you want:

```
attachment.WriteTo(ms);
```

Presumably, you want to write the decoded content of the attachment:

```
foreach(var attachment in attachments.OfType<MimePart>())
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        attachment.WriteTo(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using Content, but it says "Error CS1061". In the MimeKit class I am using (MimeKit library) there is no content variable.

Comment: Change the foreach loop to only iterate over attachments of type MimePart using the LINQ extension `.OfType<MimePart>()`